# strftime does not return abbreviated time zone

Tags: python, timezone

Can anyone tell me why the Time Zone is returned as "Mountain Daylight Time" and not as MST ?

```
import time

print time.strftime( "%H:%M %A %Z %d %b %y")
```

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows?

Comment: Was your question answered? If so, you should accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that you are using Windows, based on another question you asked.

On Windows, `strftime("%Z")` displays the `DaylightName` or `StandardName` values located at this key in the registry: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation`. Which is displayed depends (of course) on whether daylight time is in effect. If you change those settings, you must reboot for them to take effect.

On Linux, I believe (about 80% certain :-) that `strftime` uses the time zone it finds in `/etc/localtime`. On Ubuntu you set that using `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`. On Linux, `%Z` displays the timezone (e.g., mine now shows `'EDT'`, `%z` displays the offset from UTC (e.g., mine now displays `'-0400'`

Comment: as a portable solution, `pytz` module could be used: `aware_dt.tzname()` or `aware_dt.strftime('%Z')` if you want to format the time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be correct

```
import time

print time.strftime( "%H:%M %A %Z %d %b %y")

#=> 13:54 Thursday CDT 10 May 12
```

Which version of python are you running ?

Comment: I have the same thing on both Ubuntu Linux and mac-OSX 10.5 (python 2.6 for both I think...)

Comment: Ditto for OS X 10.7.4 and Python 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, and 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem using windows. As a quick and dirty solution for the 4 US timezones, you can simply remove all characters that are not capital letters from the timezone string:

```
    abbreviated_tz_str = re.sub(r'[^A-Z]', '', multiplatform_tz_str )
```

So as an example, here is how I turn a timestamp into a nice string:

```
    import re
    import time

    def nice_str( timestamp ):
        dt_str    = time.strftime( "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", time.localtime( timestamp ) )
        tz_str    = time.strftime( "%Z", time.localtime( timestamp ) )
        final_str = "%s (%s)" % ( dt_str, re.sub(r'[^A-Z]', '', tz_str ) )
        return( final_str )
```

So:

```
    print( nice_str( 1425917368 ) )
```

Shows:

```
    03/09/2015 09:09:28 AM (PDT)
```

It works, even on windows.